# complicated usage of "as something as"

Tags: phrase-meaning, comparisons, complex-sentences

> Once, of course, our satisfactions were provided by our parents, or the
> people who looked after us when we were young. And it is clearly a very
> significant moment, or series of moments, in a child’s life when he begins
> to notice that there are satisfactions outside the family.This can feel to the  child like a murder of the parents, like an act
> of outrageous and frightening ruthlessness. Or, as the philospher
> Annette Baier writes (in Reflections on How We Live) in a new twist on
> the perennial theme, ‘Parental love, paternal or maternal, **is as
> dangerous a central concept for ethics as is expert wisdom’**; because
> it leads to the perversion of authority called authoritarianism,
> morality as moralism.

I cannot deconstruct the phrase **"is as dangerous a central concept for ethics as is expert wisdom.**"

Usually the *as ... as* is used to say something like *"something is as good as other thing".*

How can I rewrite that phrase ? is this a correct rephrasing?

*the parental love is dangerous like a central concept for ethics, and dangerous like expert wisdom.*

Comment: _Usually the as ... as is used to say something like "something is as good as other thing"._ Whoever told you that!

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as

most of the examples of the above are following the formulation of as adjective as. Even if my understanding of that is wrong you can correct me no asking me who told me that ? No one, this is how I think based on the things I learned so far. If you know the answer of the question, I would appreciate your help. otherwise you can let other people help me.

Comment: It's a tweak on  'Parental love, paternal or maternal, is as dangerous a central concept for ethics as expert wisdom is.’ or simplifying the structure (semantically unacceptable, of course):  'Parental love is as dangerous a concept as expert wisdom is.’ cf 'John is as tall as Jill is.'  The inversion is licensed, in fact endorsed, by the wordiness of X and Y in 'It is as X as Y is'. It is a formal usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the "as -- as" clause, let's chop it up into separate sentences. I believe it is the multiple uses of "is", and the use of "for" in a prepositional phrase that modifies the subordinate clause, that is confusing the meaning for you.

The original:

> Parental love, paternal or maternal, is as dangerous a central concept
> for ethics as is expert wisdom

As individual sentences:

> Parental love, paternal or maternal, is, as a central concept for
> ethics, dangerous.  Also, expert wisdom is, as a central concept for
> ethics, dangerous.

The above edit changes the ["as" usage to individual subordinate clauses](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/as-because-or-since). Using ["as is -- as" as a comparative clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as) allows the writer to reduce all that verbiage. I'm going to modify an example from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as) to illustrate this usage.

The original:

> The weather this summer is as bad as last year.

Modified by replacing "is" with "are" to accommodate the plural and adding "for" as a [preposition](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/for). I've included the "for" phrasing to keep the structure closer to that in the question.

> The weather this summer is as bad for crops as are locusts.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that parental love and expert wisdom are equally dangerous concepts as far as ethics is concerned. You have to rearrange the words a little if you want to boil it down.

1. Parental love is as dangerous a central concept for ethics as is expert wisdom.
2. Parental love is a central concept as dangerous for ethics as expert wisdom is.
3. Parental love is a central concept that is as dangerous for ethics as expert wisdom is dangerous for ethics.
4. Parental love is just as dangerous for ethics as expert wisdom.